# reading spatial data from landsat 5

Tags: r, landsat

I want to read the landsat 5 data but I get an error, can you help me? I am using the RStoolbox package

```
mtlfile <- "LT05_L2SP_007068_19850806_20200918_02_T1_MTL.txt"
MTL <- readMeta (mtlfile)

Error in CRS (paste0 (c ("+ proj =", "+ zone =", "+ units = m + datum ="), pars, collapse = "")):
   No spaces permitted in PROJ4 argument-value pairs: + proj = + zone = + units = m + datum =
```

Comment: That is a really messed up proj4 string, no idea how that could happen. That line of code appears to be [readMeta.R#L176](https://github.com/bleutner/RStoolbox/blob/master/R/readMeta.R#L176), which was first introduced in [849f7f0](https://github.com/bleutner/RStoolbox/commit/849f7f0fce0b6010aefa841021b7ec14bdf09b3d) in Feb 2015, and has been largely unchanged since then. Plus the characters in your error are out of order. You might want to consider reinstalling `readMeta`.

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, you may want to `debug(readMeta)`, run your `MTL<-...` expression, and step down to the offending line (using https://github.com/bleutner/RStoolbox/blob/master/R/readMeta.R as a reference, perhaps), and then break apart each portion of that expression to see what is getting munged, *and how*. Good luck.